# Voiding 90-minute wait time for questions if original is deleted

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I would like to express my wish to have the 90 minute waiting period after questions to be voided if the original question is deleted.

Comment: Why?  What is your justification for this and what problem would it solve?  The rate limit exists for a reason (prevent new users from flooding the site with bad questions).  Being able to delete and post a new question does nothing to prevent that.

Comment: Yeah, but if someone was to write a bad question, delete it, and then come up with a good one maybe 30 minutes later, they would have to wait a full hour just to post it. If deleting the post in question was to cut down the timer a bit, such as 45 minutes, then that seems like it would be more fair and easier to use.

Comment: Every post consumes resources.  Both the site's resources and the resources of everyone who viewed the post before it was deleted.  We want you to think **before** posting, not after.  So if you write a bad question, it gets downvoted, you delete it to get your rep back, you just have to wait out the rate limit.

Comment: Also remember that negatively scored questions can factor into more strict rate limits or outright bans, even if you delete them. [Further Reading](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: @theB when I said bad question, I meant like one that I solved by myself a little later, but thanks.

Comment: Sorry if it seemed like I was implying something about your questions. (I'm not, <10k here, so I can't tell if you have deleted questions, and it doesn't apply to the discussion at hand). It's just added background for a discussion of a feature request relating to bans and deleted questions.  If the deleted post can still contribute to a ban or increased limit, then it really shouldn't be possible to reduce the cool off time between new questions.

Comment: This would be a good feature for those wishing to get an automatic post ban quickly.

Answer (score 14):

## No

This is a **Bad Idea**. It defeats the whole purpose of having question throttling in the first place, because it's open to abuse.

For example, a user posts a question. 10 minutes later, the user gets an answer, and then promptly deletes his question. Since the question is deleted, the user is now able to *immediately* ask another question, rather than have to wait the 80 additional minutes that he/she would have to wait otherwise...

Do you see where I'm going with this? Just...*no*....

Comment: Then, what about a percent knockdown off of the total wait time? It could scale with reputation, from something like 10% to 75% for higher users.

Comment: @gamehen the limit doesn't exist for higher rep users.  It exists for only low rep users.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ah, I didn't know about that.

Comment: @gamehen I don't see how a reduction in the total wait time solves the problem of abuse that I just pointed out, in any way at all. Also, if you really have such an urgent need to ask a question on Stack Overflow every 90 minutes, then you're not using Stack Overflow correctly in the first place...

Comment: Or, 10 minutes later the user *doesn't* get an answer and deletes the question...